# Averaging + Summing a range of numbers in excel based on other cell values

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a large amount of data where I have a Column A with a number x and two other columns B & C with different numbers.

I want to sum numbers in column B and take the average of the numbers in column C but only while column A has the same value.

So while x is 1 in column A I want to take the average of the numbers in Column B and sum up the numbers in Column C. If value in column a changes to 4 i want to take the sum & average of the corresponding values.

Comment: Something like `=IF(CountIf(...)<>0;SumIf(...)/CountIf(..);0)` should do the work but you'll need a list of values in A without duplicates, so copy the column elsewhere and use the function in Data tabs->Data Tools->Remove duplicates

Comment: Maybe the [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) / [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) function(s) and the [AVERAGEIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20) / [AVERAGEIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) function(s).

Comment: Hello R3uK, thanks for your reply. I think your formula is combining what I want. I need one formula for the sum and one formula for the average (The numbers are in two different colums).

Comment: @jeeped yeah i tried those for the last hour. Can't break it...

Comment: Well, let me know if you plan to post some sample data together with expected results and what you have attempted to date and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies.

I solved it with a pivot table